# Вывести лестницу из символов #

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Решаю [эту](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/staircase/submissions/code/18055351) задачу. Она простая, но на ней я решил поучиться писать рекурсию и составлять блок-схемы рекурсивных вызовов. Нужно вывести лестницу из символов `#`. Можно ли в моей реализации избавиться от третьего параметра функции `solve`, чтобы было красивее?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void solve(const string& s, int len, int n)
{
    if(s.size() > 0)
    {
        solve(s.substr(0, len - 1), len - 1, n);
        cout << string(n - len, ' ') << s << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    solve(string(n, '#'), n, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте рассмотрим вывод строки как закрытую среду. Закрытая среда для правильной работы описывается переменными, которая она принимает. В данном случае она описывается следующими минимальными знаниями:

1. Выводимый символ
2. Количество выводимых символов
3. Количество пустых символов

или так у Вас:

1. Выводимые символы
2. Количество выводимых символов
3. Длина строки, из которой высчитвается пустые символы

Вы можете избавить от параметра, только если сможете придумать систему, которая сможет принимать меньше параметров для корректной работы или систему, которая сможет ***выводить одни параметры через другие***. В данном случае есть вариант с выводом одного параметра, через другой: длину строки из самой строки. К сожалению это не третий параметр, а второй. Раз уж вы все равно size берете.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void solve(const string& s, int n)
{
    int len = s.size();
    if(len > 0)
    {
        solve(s.substr(0, len - 1), n);
        cout << string(n - len, ' ') << s << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    solve(string(n, '#'), n);
    return 0;
}
```

Ну или по хорошему, для решения требуется знать только количество символов слева и справа, если выводимые символы Вы уже знаете изначально. Их можно вывести из одной только количества общей длины + отступ в рекурсии, как это сделал @gil9red в своем ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Да легко :)

```
void solve(pair<int,int> n)
{
    if (n.first == 0) return;
    solve(make_pair(n.first-1,n.second));
    for(int i = 0; i < n.second; ++i)
        cout << ((i < n.second-n.first) ? ' ' : '#');
    cout << endl;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    solve(make_pair(n,n));
    return 0;
}
```

Просто раз вам нужна лесенка, выровненная вправо - надо как-то передать эту ширину всем вызовам. Можно параметром, можно глобальной переменной... Но знать эту ширину должен каждый вызов.

Кстати, все это можно скрыть в одной строке. Просто передаем строку из `n` символов `#`, а потом рекурсивно передавать строку с заменой первого `#` пробелом, ну, а когда вся строка - из одних пробелов, то и рекурсии конец...

Answer (score 1):

Например:

```
void solve2(int n, int max) {
    if (n > 0) {
        cout << string(n - 1, ' ') << string(max - n + 1, '#') << endl;
        solve2(n - 1, max);
    }
}

void solve2(int n) {
    solve2(n, n);
}

int main() {
    int n = 6;
//    cin >> n;

    solve(string(n, '#'), n, n);
    cout << "-----------\n";
    solve2(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Результат:

```
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
-----------
     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######
```

Comment: А без обертки можно?

Comment: А какой обертки? Попытался угадать и обновил код

Comment: solve2 над solve. Ой, не заметил, что у вас не так, как я подумал. В функции main имя solve вместо solve2, и я подумал, что вы сделали обертку для моей функции.

Comment: Плохой из меня экстрасенс )

Answer (score 1):

Результат в 0 параметров) Если цель именно это, то вот решение.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

char *z;

void Rec(){
    char *q;
    if ( q = strrchr(z,' ')  ){
        q[0] = '#';
        cout << z << endl;
        Rec();
    }
}

int main() {
    z = new char[7];
    for (int i=0;i<6;i++)
        z[i] = ' ';
    z[6] = 0;
    Rec();
    return 0;
}
```